# Network shares not available in Windows scheduled task

Tags: networking, scheduled-tasks

I have a number of scheduled tasks that run PowerShell scripts that need to access files on a Qnap NAS server. I learned some time ago that if I set "Run whether the user is logged on or not" when I defined the scheduled task I could not use the mapped drive letter to access the files on the NAS. I had to use the UNC path to access the files.

I recently wrote another script that needs to also access files on a networked PC. I just assumed that if I used the UNC path I would be able to access those files as I can with the NAS files. However, that isn't the case. I get an error that says the folder in question is not available. However, if I turn off "Run whether the user is logged on or not" the script runs as expected.

I've managed to get around it by doing a Test-Path on the UNC path and if it is not found I map the drive within the script. Then I can access the files using the UNC path. Not altogether desirable, but it works. However, I would like to understand why I'm able to access the NAS network share without any special handling, but I can't do the same with a Windows PC network share.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no question asked here.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please don't edit the answer into your question. [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. Please read [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its already been answered by the OP and does not need any more answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be a stored credentials problem. I used Windows Credential Manager to check and I found that Windows had stored the credentials for the NAS share, but had not stored the credentials for the Windows PC share. I used File Explorer to map the shared drive and to remember my credentials. After that the PowerShell was was able to access the files using the UNC path.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).